# How to run a nested Firestore query? [TypeError: doc is not a function (it is Object)]

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of "Offers", that I query within Firestore. However, for each "Offer", returned, I'd like to see if the user has used it or not. This is stored in another collection:

```
const ref = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "users", uid, "redemptions", doc.id);
```

if this document exists the user has used the offer and I should update the object with `exists: true`

I have tried to do this in the below code, however, I am getting;

```
[TypeError: doc is not a function (it is Object)]
```

### CODE

```
export const getOffers = async (id, uid) => {
  const ref = collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "venues", id, "offers");
  const q = query(ref, where("active", "==", true));
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const data = [];
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const ref = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "users", uid, "redemptions", doc.id);
    const redemptionSnapshot = getDoc(ref);
    data.push({
      id: doc.id,
      exists: redemptionSnapshot.exists(),
      ...doc.data(),
    });
  });
  return data;
};
```

I assume I cannot run another function within the forEach loop. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two meanings for `doc` in your code:

- At the top-level `doc` is a function that you import from the Firestore SDK.
- But then you re-declare `doc` in the callback here `snapshot.forEach((doc) => {`. So now `doc` is  DocumentSnapshot`.

When you call `doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "users", uid, "redemptions", doc.id)` inside the callback, `doc` refers to that `DocumentSnapshot` and not to the global function anymore. And that's why you get the error.

To solve it, give the parameter in your callback a different name. For example:

```
snapshot.forEach((docSnapshot) => {
  const ref = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "users", uid, "redemptions", docSnapshot.id);
  const redemptionSnapshot = getDoc(ref);
  data.push({
    id: docSnapshot.id,
    exists: redemptionSnapshot.exists(),
    ...docSnapshot.data(),
  });
});
```

The error message you now get will disappear when you do this.

---

You'll get another problem though as `getDoc` is an asynchronous function and your code fails to handle that. For that I recommend checking out: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of your document through `doc.data()` and from there checking if `redemptions.length` is greater than 0, or by checking its content.

This is to say that you get all sub collections and documents through doc.data(), so `doc.data().redemptions` would be a valid selector.

Comment: I have the data of the document, I want to see if the user has used the offer which will be stored in a separate collection "users/${uid}/redemptions/${doc.id}" so I need to make a query for each snapshot and then add the data true or false wether the document exists or not, I'll update my Q as maybe its not clear.