# How to construct a nested Firebase query with a for loop in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of offers and a collection of users. I am getting the list of offers but then for each offer i'd like to query the user collection to see if the user has used the offer or not.

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `forEach` function as both queries are `asynchronous`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975899/how-to-run-a-nested-firestore-query-typeerror-doc-is-not-a-function-it-is-ob/76977829#76977829).

I must therefore, use a for loop, however, I am not getting anywhere with the below code as it is returning a **Render Error** which it shouldn't.

```
export const getOffers = async (id, uid) => {
  const ref = collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "venues", id, "offers");
  const q = query(ref, where("active", "==", true));
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const data = [];

  for (snap.doc in snapshot.docs) {
    const ref = doc(
      FIREBASE_FIRESTORE,
      "users",
      uid,
      "redemptions",
      snap.doc.id
    );
    const redemptionSnapshot = await getDoc(ref);
    data.push({
      id: snap.doc.id,
      exists: redemptionSnapshot.exists(),
      ...snap.doc.data(),
    });
  }
  return data;
};
```

Comment: are you sure it's not a ReferenceError?  `for (snap.doc in snapshot.docs)` isn't valid code, it would have to be something like `for (const document in snapshot.docs)`.  Also are you sure you want `for .. in` and not `for .. of`?

Comment: @Abe "for (const document of snapshot.docs)..." has resolved the issue please add the answer thanks.

Comment: Sure. It's more along the lines of a typo, so I voted to close instead. It'll help in the future if you get in the habit of attaching full error messages and stack traces as well!